# performance degrading with PTI=on in Linux-4.4.0

Tags: linux, performance, perf

I am running a java test on Ubuntu 16.04, and i found performance difference with PTI on and off.
My host system is using CPU Ivybridge (2cores, 4 HT) 1.6GHz, with 16GB memory.

I tried to use perf to analyze where is the difference coming from, as follows.

With pti=off in grub.cfg,

```
# perf  stat -e bus-cycles,cache-misses,cache-references,L1-dcache-load-misses,dTLB-load-misses,L1-dcache-prefetch-misses,LLC-prefetches ./test.sh 

 Performance counter stats for './test.sh':

       774,986,827      bus-cycles                                                    (59.13%)
        24,044,906      cache-misses              #   12.803 % of all cache refs      (58.17%)
       187,799,652      cache-references                                              (57.51%)
       207,345,039      L1-dcache-load-misses                                         (57.65%)
        13,081,612      dTLB-load-misses                                              (58.85%)
        22,678,453      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses                                     (59.62%)
        24,089,506      LLC-prefetches                                                (59.99%)

       6.210151360 seconds time elapsed
```

and, with pti=on (default settings in Linux kernel), I got,

```
# perf stat -e bus-cycles,cache-misses,cache-references,L1-dcache-load-misses,dTLB-load-misses,L1-dcache-prefetch-misses,LLC-prefetches ./test.sh
```

Performance counter stats for './test.sh':

```
 1,205,903,578      bus-cycles                                                    (57.92%)
    23,877,107      cache-misses              #   13.167 % of all cache refs      (57.31%)
   181,340,147      cache-references                                              (57.46%)
   206,177,901      L1-dcache-load-misses                                         (58.42%)
    63,285,591      dTLB-load-misses                                              (59.06%)
    24,012,988      L1-dcache-prefetch-misses                                     (58.65%)
    24,928,410      LLC-prefetches                                                (58.23%)

  10.344839116 seconds time elapsed
```

test.sh is the program to be profiled, from above perf output, test.sh took more time with pti=on than with pti=off, but event output is NOT clear where the difference comes from.
Is there any other perf event can help in this case ?

Updated with more perf events.
PTI=off

```
# perf stat --repeat 5 -e cache-references,cache-misses,cpu-cycles,ref-cycles,faults,L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-icache-load-misses,branches,branch-misses,node-loads,node-load-misses,instructions,cs java mytest

 Performance counter stats for 'java mytest' (5 runs):

         8,711,306      cache-references                                              ( +-  4.13% )  (48.49%)
         1,290,234      cache-misses              #   14.811 % of all cache refs      ( +-  4.04% )  (49.44%)
       709,587,381      cpu-cycles                                                    ( +-  1.44% )  (48.91%)
       671,299,480      ref-cycles                                                    ( +-  1.95% )  (58.09%)
             5,918      faults                                                        ( +-  0.12% )
       185,928,475      L1-dcache-loads                                               ( +-  4.29% )  (35.90%)
         9,249,983      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    4.98% of all L1-dcache hits    ( +-  5.91% )  (27.84%)
         4,718,632      L1-icache-load-misses                                         ( +-  5.47% )  (20.83%)
       106,021,866      branches                                                      ( +-  1.98% )  (31.56%)
         4,487,091      branch-misses             #    4.23% of all branches          ( +-  5.35% )  (40.34%)
           450,170      node-loads                                                    ( +-  9.18% )  (38.32%)
                 0      node-load-misses                                              (40.62%)
       509,344,631      instructions              #    0.72  insns per cycle          ( +-  5.59% )  (49.64%)
               458      cs                                                            ( +-  2.05% )

       0.216794242 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  3.44% )
```

PTI=ON

```
# perf stat --repeat 5 -e cache-references,cache-misses,cpu-cycles,ref-cycles,faults,L1-dcache-loads,L1-dcache-load-misses,L1-icache-load-misses,branches,branch-misses,node-loads,node-load-misses,instructions,cs java mytest

 Performance counter stats for 'java mytest' (5 runs):

        10,109,469      cache-references                                              ( +-  4.10% )  (44.67%)
         1,360,012      cache-misses              #   13.453 % of all cache refs      ( +-  2.16% )  (45.28%)
     1,199,960,141      cpu-cycles                                                    ( +-  2.44% )  (46.13%)
     1,086,243,141      ref-cycles                                                    ( +-  1.28% )  (54.64%)
             5,923      faults                                                        ( +-  0.24% )
       163,902,394      L1-dcache-loads                                               ( +-  3.46% )  (41.91%)
         8,588,505      L1-dcache-load-misses     #    5.24% of all L1-dcache hits    ( +-  5.59% )  (27.82%)
         5,576,811      L1-icache-load-misses                                         ( +-  3.87% )  (18.41%)
       117,508,300      branches                                                      ( +-  3.98% )  (27.34%)
         4,878,640      branch-misses             #    4.15% of all branches          ( +-  2.28% )  (35.55%)
           585,464      node-loads                                                    ( +-  9.05% )  (34.55%)
                 0      node-load-misses                                              (36.68%)
       614,773,322      instructions              #    0.51  insns per cycle          ( +-  4.11% )  (46.10%)
               476      cs                                                            ( +-  2.75% )

       0.375871969 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.81% )
```

Comment: You should really use `ocperf.py` (https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools) and use meaningful HW-specific names for HW events.  I think `cache-references` is actually L3 loads or something on Intel SnB-family.  See also other x86 asm performance info / links in the x86 tag wiki https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea what event "bus cycles" is actually measuring.  core clock cycles is usually more relevant.

But anyway, PTI=on makes every system call (and other entry into the kernel) more expensive, because it has to modify the x86 CR3 control register (setting a new page table top-level pointer).  This is literally how it isolates user-space from having access to kernel page-tables.

**Note the big increase in `dTLB-load-misses`**.  With process-context IDs (PCID) support, PTI might be able to avoid fully flushing the TLB every time it enters the kernel.  But I don't know the details.  (Without PCID, replacing the page tables invalidates the entire TLB.)

You could use `strace -c` to time system calls.

With `perf record` (with sufficient privileges), you can record samples that include kernel code, so you can see which instructions in the kernel actually took a long time.  (mov to CR3 takes time as well, and so does Spectre mitigation, which is separate from Meltdown mitigation (PTI).  But I think *most* of the cost of Meltdown mitigation is the TLB misses over time inside the kernel and again after returning to user-space, not from the actual swapping page tables.)